# GNS3 - hosted or VM?

Tags: cisco, tcp, network, gns3

I know that there is a gns3 client that is installed in the operating system.

but i see there is a gns3 for vm

that gns3 for VM In a few words it is a virtual software to use it with a hypervisor

It's a bit confusing, I can't understand

Answer (score 1):

The GNS3 VM distribution is an optimized Linux VM that comes already configured to optimally run the included GNS3 simulator.

Using the VM, you save yourself the effort of tweaking your hosted installation, especially on Windows or macOS.

Your question is answered [here](https://docs.gns3.com/docs/emulators/which-emulators-should-i-use) more extensively:

> ## Use GNS3 VM or not?
>
> The GNS3 VM is recommended for most situations when you are using
> Windows or Mac OS.
>
> The GNS3 development team have worked hard to create a lightweight,
> robust way of creating GNS3 topologies that avoids multiple common
> issues experienced when using a local install of GNS3. This includes
> the lack of proper Qemu support when running VIRL natively on Windows
> (not recommended), as well as a method to easily add docker containers
> to your projects.
>
> However, if you only want to create basic GNS3 topologies using Cisco
> IOS routers, a local (Dynamips) install will suffice. This means that
> you only install the GNS3 GUI (all-in-one).
>
> This is simpler in some ways to set up, but does have limitations and
> should be seen as the starting point in your GNS3 journey. As soon as
> you are comfortable with GNS3, it is recommended that you move to a
> GNS3 VM setup to make the most of GNS3 options and optimization.